# Need help with $\arccos$ equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification, roots

I have the equation

$$ \cos(2x + \frac{\pi}{9}) = 0.5$$

I know that in order to solve for $x\in \Bbb R$, I need to use

$$\arccos(0.5) = 2x + \frac{\pi}{9} $$

This yields

$$  2x + \frac{\pi}{9} =
\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{3} + 2k\pi,  & \text{Positive angle} \\
2 \pi - \frac{\pi}{3}+ 2k\pi, & \text{Negative angle}
\end{cases} $$

I would then subtract $\frac{\pi}{9}$ from both sides and get:

$$  2x  =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2\pi}{9} + 2k\pi,  & \text{Positive angle} \\
\frac{14\pi}{9}+ 2k\pi, & \text{Negative angle}
\end{cases} $$

However according to the handout the correct solution is:

$$  2x  =
\begin{cases}
\frac{4\pi}{9} + 2k\pi,  & \text{Positive angle} \\
\frac{16\pi}{9}+ 2k\pi, & \text{Negative angle}
\end{cases} $$

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You don't need help. The handout's author does. :)

Comment: WThe handout's solution is wrong. It's easy to see the second line cannot be true.

Comment: The solution in the handout would be correct if the original problem were $$\cos\left(2x - \frac{\pi}{9}\right) = 0.5$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $\;\cos x=\alpha\implies x=\pm\arccos x\;$. Besides this, we only need basic trigonometry to solve that equation:

$$\cos t=\frac12\iff t=\pm\frac\pi3+2k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\implies$$

puting $\;t=2x+\frac\pi9\;$ we get

$$2x+\frac\pi9=\pm\frac\pi3+2k\pi\implies\begin{cases}2x=\cfrac{2\pi}9+2k\pi,&\text{(positive solution)}\\{}\\
2x=-\cfrac{4\pi}9+2k\pi=\cfrac{14\pi}9+2k\pi,&\text{(negative solution)}\end{cases}\;,\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

Thus you're right, the handout's solution is wrong.

Comment: I will write $ x=\pm\arccos x+2\Bbb Z\pi$. +1 for my tastes.